# How do I catch an asynchronous error from a function without promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, try-catch

The specific function that I want to catch errors is from the Node.JS HTTP module:

```
response.write(data);
```

This function does not return a promise and is asynchronous so putting it in a try/catch doesn't work either. It does take an optional callback argument but this is only called on success of the operation. I also can't use await as this is function is not defined as an async function.

What is the best method for handling errors thrown by this function?

Comment: As `response` [extends](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) `Stream`, maybe you can use [`error` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_error) listener for writable streams.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback):

> The `write()` method […] calls the supplied `callback` once the data has
> been fully handled. If an error occurs, the `callback` *may or may not* be
> called with the error as its first argument. To reliably detect write
> errors, add a listener for the `'error'` event.